# What is meant by "new packages" in apt upgrade?

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management

The documentation for `apt upgrade` says:

> upgrade is used to install available upgrades of all packages
>   currently installed on the system from the sources configured via
>   sources.list(5). New packages will be installed if required to satisfy
>   dependencies, but existing packages will never be removed. If an
>   upgrade for a package requires the remove of an installed package the
>   upgrade for this package isn't performed.

But what I am confused about is what is meant by "new packages" here. For example, let's say I installed CUDA 10.0, by downloading the .deb file and installing it with dpkg. I also know that there is a CUDA 10.1 version. Would running `sudo apt upgrade cuda` then delete all of my CUDA 10.0 files / libraries / documentation, and install the equivalents but for CUDA 10.1? Or would it install these files alongside CUDA 10.0? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

`apt upgrade` will upgrade only the packages installed from Ubuntu repositories.

It won't upgrade any packages installed by downloading `deb` files unless the same packages exist in the repositories.

So your `cuda` won't be upgraded.

Also `apt upgrade` doesn't take a package as a parameter.

See `man apt` for more details.

There is `nvidia-cuda-toolkit` package version 9.1.85-3ubuntu1 in the 18.04 repos. So your 10.0 should be safe anyway.